# Javascript - Gecko border radius adaptation on HTML Canvas (CSS border-radius)

Tags: javascript, css, math, canvas, gecko

I'm trying to figure out how to reproduce the behavior of the "border-radius" css property into an HTML canvas.

So i've already done something in Javascript in order to compute the correct borders of a given shape, using a specific radius (for each corner).

*Here is the previous question if needed : [Gecko - CSS layout border radius - Javascript conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48466238/gecko-css-layout-border-radius-javascript-conversion/48475543)*

I've managed to get close from the browser adaptation but there's still an issue, and it seems that it's the last, and the hard part!

**Let's take an example in order to explain you the problem**

Take a shape of `100px` width & `100px` height. Now apply the following radius to each corner :

- Top left : 37px
- Top right :  100px
- Bottom right : 1px
- Bottom left : 100px

So the css style for this will be `border-radius : 37px 100px 1px 100px`

Now let's consider using **the code below** in order to draw this shape in a canvas.

By using the function `correctRadius(r, w, h)` in order to avoid bad shapes, each corners will be computed like that :

=> `{tl: 18.5, tr: 81.5, br: 0.5, bl: 81.5}`

**Here is a visual of this :**

[image: calc problem css border radius canvas]

> You will be able to test it in the following snippet

As you can see, the browser shape (green) is overlapped with the canvas shape (brown + 'pink' due to opacity). I've put some opacity on it in order to check the bad corners (pink).

The brown shape do not fit properly into the green shape, **the top left corner** is getting out of the base, and **the bottom left and top right corners** don't fit the green shape.

I've already tried to fix that but with no success, and also looked the sources of the Gecko layout engine (https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev) in this file : `layout/painting/nsCSSRenderingBorders.cpp`, but haven't found anything + i have no skills in C++

---

If anyone could help me to figure this out, or give me some advice, i'll be able to fix this and get the borders working

```js
// Ctx
var ctx = document.getElementById("rounded-rect").getContext("2d");
ctx.translate(0, 0);

function correctRadius(r, w, h) {
  var tl = r.tl;
  var tr = r.tr;
  var br = r.br;
  var bl = r.bl;


  r.tl -= Math.max(Math.max((tl + tr - w) / 2, 0),
    Math.max((tl + bl - h) / 2, 0));

  r.tr -= Math.max(Math.max((tr + tl - w) / 2, 0),
    Math.max((tr + br - h) / 2, 0));

  r.br -= Math.max(Math.max((br + bl - w) / 2, 0),
    Math.max((br + tr - h) / 2, 0));

  r.bl -= Math.max(Math.max((bl + br - w) / 2, 0),
    Math.max((bl + tl - h) / 2, 0));


}


//Round rect func
ctx.constructor.prototype.fillRoundedRect =
  function(xx, yy, ww, hh, rad, fill, stroke) {
    correctRadius(rad, ww, hh);
    if (typeof(rad) === "undefined") rad = 5;
    this.beginPath();
    this.moveTo(xx, yy);
    this.arcTo(xx + ww, yy, xx + ww, yy + hh, rad.tr);
    this.arcTo(xx + ww, yy + hh, xx, yy + hh, rad.br);
    this.arcTo(xx, yy + hh, xx, yy, rad.bl);
    this.arcTo(xx, yy, xx + ww, yy, rad.tl);
    if (stroke) this.stroke(); // Default to no stroke
    if (fill || typeof(fill) === "undefined") this.fill(); // Default to fill
  };

ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.strokeStyle = "#ddf";

var copy = document.getElementById('copy');
var tl = document.getElementById('tl');
var tr = document.getElementById('tr');
var bl = document.getElementById('bl');
var br = document.getElementById('br');

var last = [];
setInterval(function() {


  /* 1.Top left */
  /* 2. Top right */
  /* 3. Bottom right  */
  /* 4. Bottom left */

  var bordersCSSProps = [
      "border-top-left-radius",
      "border-top-right-radius",
      "border-bottom-right-radius",
      "border-bottom-left-radius"
    ],
    elementBorders = [],
    elementStyle = getComputedStyle(copy);

  var changed = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    elementBorders[i] = elementStyle.getPropertyValue(bordersCSSProps[i]);
    if (elementBorders[i] !== last[i]) {
      changed = true;
      last[i] = elementBorders[i];
    }
  }

  if (changed) {

    var borders = [].concat(elementBorders).map(function(a) {
      return parseInt(a)
    });
    var rad = {
      tl: borders[0],
      tr: borders[1],
      br: borders[2],
      bl: borders[3]
    };

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 500);


    ctx.fillRoundedRect(120, 120, 100, 100, rad);


  }
}, 1E3 / 60);


function elemBordersSet() {
  var borders = [tl.value, tr.value, br.value, bl.value].join('px ') + 'px';
  copy.style.borderRadius = borders;

}

tl.oninput = elemBordersSet;
tr.oninput = elemBordersSet;
bl.oninput = elemBordersSet;
br.oninput = elemBordersSet;
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:inline-block; position: absolute;
left:120px;top:120px; width: 100px; height: 100px; background:green;

border-radius:  100px 49px 1px 1px;" id="copy">

</div>

<canvas style="opacity:0.5; z-index:1; display: inline-block; position: absolute; left:0; top:0;" id="rounded-rect" width="600" height="500">

</canvas>


<div style="margin-top:250px; position:absolute; z-index:5">
  <label>
        Top left
        <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="tl"></label><br/>
  <label>
        Top right
        <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="tr"></label><br/>
  <label>
        Bottom left
        <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="bl"></label><br/>
  <label>
        Bottom right
        <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="0" class="slider" id="br"></label><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: it seems to be more complicated than i suspected in the previous question :) I guess we have to do with some rounding, we need to apply some floor/ceil but not sure how exactly

Comment: Yeah :/ Still working on it ! :)

Comment: Struggling to get the solution ... Anyone have a tip or a start of working pattern ?

Comment: yes not easy at all, i tried a lot of thing yesterday without any clue :s you may consider adding a bounty to it if you get nothing

Comment: I'm trying to do it with a sort of ratio. But still no clue. I think i can't do that , because of my low (new) reputation :S

Comment: will do it for you ;) but we need to wait to be able to activate the bounty

Comment: Really ? Thanks ! :)

Comment: I may be on a good way, i'll keep you updated ! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Found the solution !

We just need to compute a `scaleRatio` :

First, we get the `maxRadiusWidth` (r.tl + r.tr, r.bl + r.br) & `maxRadiusHeight` (r.tl + r.bl, r.tr + r.br)

**and then** a `widthRatio = (w / maxRadiusWidth)`  & `heightRatio = (h / maxRadiusHeight)` with the size of the shape (WIDTH & HEIGHT)

Then we take the lower of theses two variables : `Math.min(Math.min(widthRatio, heightRatio), 1)` in order to not get out of the shape & we make sure that
the ratio is below 1.

**Finally**, we simply need to multiply each corner by this ratio in order to get the correct size !

```
r.tl = tl*scaleRatio;
r.tr = tr*scaleRatio;
r.br = br*scaleRatio;
r.bl = bl*scaleRatio;
```

**See snippet below ;)**

```js
// Ctx
var ctx = document.getElementById("rounded-rect").getContext("2d");
ctx.translate(0, 0);

function correctRadius(r, w, h) {

        var
            maxRadiusWidth = Math.max(r.tl + r.tr, r.bl + r.br),
            maxRadiusHeight = Math.max(r.tl + r.bl, r.tr + r.br),
            widthRatio = w / maxRadiusWidth,
            heightRatio = h / maxRadiusHeight,
            scaleRatio = Math.min(Math.min(widthRatio, heightRatio), 1);


        for (var k in r)
            r[k] = r[k] * scaleRatio;

}


//Round rect func
ctx.constructor.prototype.fillRoundedRect =
    function(xx, yy, ww, hh, rad, fill, stroke) {
        correctRadius(rad, ww, hh);
        if (typeof(rad) === "undefined") rad = 5;
        this.beginPath();
        this.moveTo(xx, yy);
        this.arcTo(xx + ww, yy, xx + ww, yy + hh, rad.tr);
        this.arcTo(xx + ww, yy + hh, xx, yy + hh, rad.br);
        this.arcTo(xx, yy + hh, xx, yy, rad.bl);
        this.arcTo(xx, yy, xx + ww, yy, rad.tl);
        if (stroke) this.stroke(); // Default to no stroke
        if (fill || typeof(fill) === "undefined") this.fill(); // Default to fill
    };

ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.strokeStyle = "#ddf";

var copy = document.getElementById('copy');
var tl = document.getElementById('tl');
var tr = document.getElementById('tr');
var bl = document.getElementById('bl');
var br = document.getElementById('br');

var last = [];
setInterval(function() {


    /* 1.Top left */
    /* 2. Top right */
    /* 3. Bottom right  */
    /* 4. Bottom left */

    var bordersCSSProps = [
            "border-top-left-radius",
            "border-top-right-radius",
            "border-bottom-right-radius",
            "border-bottom-left-radius"
        ],
        elementBorders = [],
        elementStyle = getComputedStyle(copy);

    var changed = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        elementBorders[i] = elementStyle.getPropertyValue(bordersCSSProps[i]);
        if (elementBorders[i] !== last[i]) {
            changed = true;
            last[i] = elementBorders[i];
        }
    }

    if (changed) {

        var borders = [].concat(elementBorders).map(function(a) {
            return parseInt(a)
        });
        var rad = {
            tl: borders[0],
            tr: borders[1],
            br: borders[2],
            bl: borders[3]
        };

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 500);


        ctx.fillRoundedRect(120, 120, 100, 200, rad);


    }
}, 1E3 / 60);


function elemBordersSet() {
    var borders = [tl.value, tr.value, br.value, bl.value].join('px ') + 'px';
    copy.style.borderRadius = borders;

}

tl.oninput = elemBordersSet;
tr.oninput = elemBordersSet;
bl.oninput = elemBordersSet;
br.oninput = elemBordersSet;
```

```html
<div style="display:inline-block; position: absolute;
left:120px;top:120px; width: 100px; height: 200px; background:green;

border-radius: 33px 71px 40px 100px;" id="copy">

</div>

<canvas style="z-index: 1;opacity:0.4;display: inline-block; position: absolute; left:0; top:0;" id="rounded-rect"
    width="600"
    height="500">

</canvas>


<div style="position: absolute; z-index: 5;margin-top: 330px;">
<label>
    Top left
    <input type="range" min="1" max="500" value="0" class="slider" id="tl"></label><br/>
<label>
    Top right
    <input type="range" min="1" max="500" value="0" class="slider" id="tr"></label><br/>
<label>
    Bottom left
    <input type="range" min="1" max="500" value="0" class="slider" id="bl"></label><br/>
<label>
    Bottom right
    <input type="range" min="1" max="500" value="0" class="slider" id="br"></label><br/>
</div>
```