# replicate CSS border-radius with canvas API

Tags: javascript, html, css, math, canvas

I want to reproduce the following CSS shape into a canvas. It has the following properties :

```
width: 325px;
height: 200px;
background: green;
border-radius: 60px 110px / 100px 80px;
```

[image: the rendered shape]

I already have a function to make rounded rectangles, but not so deformed... See associated stack post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48491607/9264003

I've tried `bezierCurveTo()` & `arcTo()` functions, but with no success.

I think we have to compute an oval for each corner: Top-left, Top-Right, Bottom-Right, Bottom-Left, but I am not sure at all...

If anyone were to reproduce this shape, or give me any tip or formula in order to compute this that would be a very good start !

Comment: When dealing with complex shapes you have to ask the shape from the designer in `<svg>` form. `<svg>` is not an image, it's a document and it contains lines of code. It was designed specifically to cover cases like yours. You could use various programs to generate it yourself, but normally it's not the coder's job to create `<svg>`s.

Comment: Can I ask what's wrong with my solution to your pre-edit question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually an [`ellipse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/ellipse) method for the 2DContext API. Its browser support is not awesome, but it can be [polyfilled](https://github.com/google/canvas-5-polyfill).

Using this method simplifies a lot the operation, since we can just use it to draw a quarter of ellipse at every corners, but it doesn't solve the whole problem...

You will still have to parse the CSSString to know how to draw your ellipses, for this, I use a simple dummy div + getComputedStyle.
According to specs, if one of the two border-XXX-XXX-radius computed values is `0px`, then we should draw a squared corner.
You will also have to account for [overlapping corners rule](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#corner-overlap), and for this, I borrowed niklasvh's [html2canvas implementation](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/8788a9f458f538c004a626c5ce7ee24b53e48c1c/src/Bounds.js#L200) of the CSSWG algo.

Here is my attempt to create such a Border-radius function to canvas, but I didn't made extensive tests, so it might fail.

Also note that it only accepts the shorthand `border-radius` CSS syntax, though it wuold be easy to tweak if you also want to pass long-hand ones.

```js
var w = c.width = 325,
  h = c.height = 200,
  ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';

inp.onchange = function() {
  blurb.style.borderRadius = this.value;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  drawBorderRadius(ctx, this.value, w, h);
  ctx.fill();
};
inp.onchange();

function drawBorderRadius(ctx, CSSRule, w, h) {
  var radii = parseBorderRadiusRules(CSSRule);
  fixOverlappingCorners(radii);

  ctx.beginPath();
  var x, y, h_, v_;

  // top-left corner
  if (hasZero(radii.topleft))
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  else {
    x = radii.topleft[0];
    y = radii.topleft[1];
    ctx.ellipse(x, y, x, y, 0, Math.PI, Math.PI * 1.5);
  }
  // top-right corner
  if (hasZero(radii.topright))
    ctx.lineTo(w, 0);
  else {
    x = radii.topright[0];
    y = radii.topright[1];
    ctx.ellipse(w - radii.topright[0], y, x, y, 0, -Math.PI / 2, 0);
  }
  //bottom-right corner
  if (hasZero(radii.bottomright))
    ctx.lineTo(w, h);
  else {
    x = radii.bottomright[0];
    y = radii.bottomright[1];
    ctx.ellipse(w - x, h - y, x, y, 0, 0, Math.PI / 2);
  }
  //bottom-left corner
  if (hasZero(radii.bottomleft))
    ctx.lineTo(0, h);
  else {
    x = radii.bottomleft[0];
    y = radii.bottomleft[1];
    ctx.ellipse(x, h - y, x, y, 0, Math.PI / 2, Math.PI);
  }

  // we need to check if one value is zero in order to draw a squared corner in such case
  function hasZero(corner) {
    return !Array.isArray(corner) ||
      corner.indexOf(0) > -1 ||
      corner.indexOf(NaN) > -1;
  }
  // returns a dictionnary of four corners [horizontal, vertical] values as px
  function parseBorderRadiusRules(CSSstring) {
    var elem = document.createElement('div');
    elem.style.borderRadius = CSSstring;
    elem.style.width = w;
    elem.style.height = h;
    elem.style.position = 'absolute';
    elem.zIndex = -999;
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
    var computed = getComputedStyle(elem);
    var radii = {
      topleft: cleanRule(computed['border-top-left-radius']),
      topright: cleanRule(computed['border-top-right-radius']),
      bottomright: cleanRule(computed['border-bottom-right-radius']),
      bottomleft: cleanRule(computed['border-bottom-left-radius'])
    };
    document.body.removeChild(elem);

    return radii;

    function cleanRule(str) {
      var xy = str.split(' ');
      if (xy.length === 1) {
        xy[1] = xy[0];
      }
      return xy.map(toPx);
    }

    function toPx(str, index) {
      var val = parseFloat(str);
      if (str.indexOf('%') > -1) {
        return percentageToPx(val, !index ? w : h);
      }
      return val;
    }

    function percentageToPx(percent, length) {
      return length * (percent / 100);
    }
  }
  // borrowed from https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/8788a9f458f538c004a626c5ce7ee24b53e48c1c/src/Bounds.js#L200
  // https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/master/LICENSE
  function fixOverlappingCorners(radii) {
    var factors = [
        w / (radii.topleft[0] + radii.topright[0]),
        w / (radii.bottomleft[0] + radii.bottomright[0]),
        h / (radii.topleft[1] + radii.bottomleft[1]),
        h / (radii.topright[1] + radii.bottomright[1])
      ],
      minFactor = Math.min.apply(null, factors);
      
    if (minFactor <= 1) {
      for (var key in radii) {
        radii[key] = radii[key].map(scale);
      }
    }

    function scale(value) {
      return value * minFactor;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#blurb {
  width: 325px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}

input:checked+.cont>#blurb {
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
}

.cont {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<input id="inp" value="60px 110px / 100px 80px">
<label>overlap</label><input type="checkbox">
<div class="cont">
  <div id="blurb"></div>
  <canvas id="c"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: @Backspace as I said, I don't really had time to work out this algo, but it came to my mind that niklasvh already made it for his html2canvas script. The part we are interested in [can be found here](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/8788a9f458f538c004a626c5ce7ee24b53e48c1c/src/Bounds.js#L200). I hope I'll have time tomorrow to improve this answer...

Comment: Wow, thanks ! That's a very good way to do it, but it appears that some "bugs" left, see : [Bug screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/YxOsI) . I will try to fix this, but if you can get it work totally (if you have time), i would really appreciate it :S

Comment: Well it seems that the "100% 10px / 100px 80px rule" is now working correctly. But i've tested another one and it's not good as the browser (see [Bug screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/Rd9rv) ). Otherwise, html2canvas renders it perfectly, see : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rorqn4oj/1/)

Comment: @Backspace done... I misread, it should have been `h / sum(topleftvertical, bottomleftvertical)` instead of `h / sum(topleftvertical, toprightvertical)`

Comment: Seems that everything is now working ! A big thanks, that is a deserved accepted answer !

Answer (score 0):

Here it is as an SVG, using arc segments:

```
<path d="M 60,0 225,0 A 100,80 0 0 1 325,80 L 325,90 A 60,110 0 0 1 265,200 L 100,200 A 100,80 0 0 1 0,120 L 0,110 A 60,110 0 0 1 60,0 Z" />
```

Screenshot in Inkscape:

[image: Screenshot]

Depending what you're trying to do, it may be simplest just to use SVG and forget canvas.

But if you really need this to be on a canvas, you can build the same thing with arcs but it's trickier because [`arcTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arcTo) does only circular arcs, not elliptical ones.

One way to get around that is to change the scaling of the drawing context before drawing each arc.

Here's an example:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function ellipticalArcTo(x1, y1, x2, y2, rx, ry) {
  ctx.save();
  const xScale = 1;
  const yScale = ry / rx;
  ctx.scale(xScale, yScale);
  ctx.arcTo(x1 / xScale, y1 / yScale, x2 / xScale, y2 / yScale, rx);
  ctx.restore();
}

ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx.beginPath();

ctx.moveTo(60, 0);
ctx.lineTo(225, 0);
ellipticalArcTo(325, 0, 325, 80, 100, 80);
ctx.lineTo(325, 90);
ellipticalArcTo(325, 200, 215, 200, 60, 110);
ctx.lineTo(100, 200);
ellipticalArcTo(0, 200, 0, 120, 100, 80);
ctx.lineTo(0, 110);
ellipticalArcTo(0, 0, 60, 0, 60, 110);

ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

Note that I haven't tested this with any rotated arcs. For all I know, it's broken when the major axes are not horizontal and vertical. But you don't need this to simulate border-radius of a rectangle.